# How to access the channel dimensions of a tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have an output of tensor shape [32,24,24,6] i.e [batch_size,height,width,channel dimension] . I want to access the channel dimension values and work on it,  maybe get it as a tuple or list of tensors which i plan to use in the elems of tf.map_fn. I tried using indexing([-1, -1, -1, 0:6]) but i am not sure if it is right way. Is there a right way in which i can access the channel dimension ? Can i try tensor.get_shape().as_list() and then access by using for loop?I am confused, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by accessing the channel dimension.  We use the last dimension of an array in the same way as another. `arr[0,:,:,:]` is first batch, an 'image'. `arr[:,:,:,0]` is the first 'channel' for all batches and 'pixels'.  `arr[0,0,0,:]` is one 'pixel', all 6 values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keras backend, which also works in graph mode. Here an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
testTensor = tf.random.uniform(shape = (32,128,128,3))
shape = tf.keras.backend.int_shape(testTensor) # (32,128,128,3)
```

Comment: But this will give me just the tensor shape as tuple of integer , what i need is to access the channel dimension or split the channel dimension and then work on it, i.e. after getting the channel dimension values i can make a tuple or list of them. Maybe i can use tf.split for this purpose